# How to transform and combine two DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-loc

I'm trying to assign dataframe columns to the row and column of the `.loc` function. I have a DataFrame `df` with no set index, with `Sites` and `Visits` as my column headers

| Index | Site | Visit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 101 | Visit 1 |
| 1 | 102 | Visit 1 |
| 2 | 102 | Visit 2 |

I have another dataframe `df2` with `Sites` as my dataframe index, and `Visits` as my columns with `Cost` as my values.

| Index | Visit 1 | Visit 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 50 | 60 |
| 102 | 100 | 120 |

I'm trying to use `.loc` to index the `Cost` from `df2` and add it as a column to `df1` like so

| Index | Site | Visit | Cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 101 | Visit 1 | 50 |
| 1 | 102 | Visit 1 | 60 |
| 2 | 102 | Visit 2 | 120 |

I tried using the following code to provide a row and column value

```
df['Cost'] = df2.loc[df['Site'],df['Visit']]
```

But I got the following error:

```
KeyError: "Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing labels is no longer supported. 
The following labels were missing: etc. etc.
```

Any idea how to use two column values from one DataFrame as the `.loc` row and column values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- This is a question about merging, but the dataframes should be transformed, in order to properly merge them.

### Transform the dataframes

- Transform `df2` by stacking `'Visit 1'` and `'Visit 2'` into a single column, with the values in an adjacent column
- Technically, the columns do not need to be renamed, as is done below. However, I think it makes it easier when creating the [`.merge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

```py
import pandas as pd

# create df1
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Index': ['0', '1', '2'], 'Site': ['101', '102', '102'], 'Visit': ['Visit 1', 'Visit 1', 'Visit 2']})

# drop the Index column
df1.drop(columns=['Index'], inplace=True)

# display(df1)
  Site    Visit
0  101  Visit 1
1  102  Visit 1
2  102  Visit 2

# create df2
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Index': ['101', '102'], 'Visit 1': ['50', '100'], 'Visit 2': ['60', '120']})

# display(df2)
  Index Visit 1 Visit 2
0   101      50      60
1   102     100     120

# stack Visit 1 and Visit 2 into a single column
df2 = df2.set_index('Index').stack().reset_index()

# rename the columns
df2.columns = ['Site', 'Visit', 'Cost']

# display(df2)
  Site    Visit Cost
0  101  Visit 1   50
1  101  Visit 2   60
2  102  Visit 1  100
3  102  Visit 2  120
```

### Merge the dataframes

- See [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

```py
cost = df1.merge(df2, on=['Site', 'Visit'])

# display(cost)
  Site    Visit Cost
0  101  Visit 1   50
1  102  Visit 1  100
2  102  Visit 2  120
```

Answer (score 2):

you can also use [`DataFrame.join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) with `df2.stack`'s index to achieve the target.

```py
df1 = df1.set_index('Index')
df2 = df2.set_index('Index')
df_reuslt = df1.join(df2.stack().rename('Cost'),
                     on=['Site', 'Visit'])

print(df_reuslt)

#            Site    Visit  Cost
#     Index                     
#     0       101  Visit 1    50
#     1       102  Visit 1   100
#     2       102  Visit 2   120
```